# Play framework 2.5 logs `?` question marks instead of line numbers

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, logback, playframework-2.5

I have a play framework app with all standard configurations. I modify `logback.xml` like this:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} %L - %message%n%xException{10} </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

I tried instead of `%L`  put there `%line`, `%class`, etc. - all to the same result, it outputs `?` in the log message, like this:

```
[info] application ? - Checking cart...
```

I also tried to follow the accepted answer to this question: [Scala Play framework: logger pattern for displaying file and line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565385/scala-play-framework-logger-pattern-for-displaying-file-and-line)
and put `val logger = Logger(this.getClass)` inside my class. Still same result. Is there any way to fix it? Logback version specified in build.sbt is `2.11`.

Comment: Try to add `<includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>` inside your `appender` tag

Comment: nope didn't help. also tried `<appender includeCallerData="true"`

Answer (score 5):

I add `includeCallerData` and work

```
   <appender  name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `%L` as in your question works perfectly for me in both Play 2.4 and Play 2.5 (exact versions: `2.4.6` and `2.5.12`).

I note however that I **do not** explicitly state any desired version of logback in either application's `build.sbt`.

This results in (for the Play 2.5 app):

```
+-com.typesafe.play:play-logback_2.11:2.5.12 [S]
| +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7
| | +-ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.7
| | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.20 (evicted by: 1.7.21)
| | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
```

(dependency tree via the [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin)

If you're seeing a different logback version, try removing any explicit dependency declaration, so that you see the same library versions in your dependency tree.

Hope it helps.