# Logback's "method" Conversion Word outputs question mark "?" when using AsyncAppender

Tags: java, logback, jul-to-slf4j

Logback offers [`method` conversion word](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#method) however on my machine it outputs only question mark symbol when using AsyncAppender:

```
2020-09-09 12:14:57.551 IOService.?: Reading network …
2020-09-09 12:14:57.551 SocketIO.?: SOCKET - Writing data…
```

I'm using relatively simple configuration:

```xml
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0}.%method: %msg %n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

When switching to regular FileAppender (e.g. `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender`) it works fine.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `includeCallerData` to the `ASYNCSTDOUT` appender and it work.
There is code:

```
<appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
</appender>
```

Look there for the original [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51270052/2590966)